# What should be the maximum file upload size for a .Net Core API?

Tags: .net, api, http, asp.net-core, file-upload

Hello I Am currently looking into improving an API endpoint for uploading files. The project I am currently working on has the file extensions and maximum file size that the API accepts hardcoded in an helper class. But I am currently working on a flexible solution for mutliple endpoints that would accept different file extensions and file sizes. But I was curious to what is actually a best practice for maximum file sizes. Since I did not really find a conclusive answer yet. I would suggest that the maximum file size should depend on the uploaded file types in our project case it would be compressed media files except video formats.
But I would not know for sure but are there any best practices and what should be the maximum file upload size?

Comment: Do you want to change the size according to every file?

Answer (score 2):

Because setting the size need to change two places. Asp.net core allows you to upload the files up to 28M, above the action, you can change it according to flexible solution. But it involves iis, it only set once when you run the application.

According to this situation, you have to set a larger file size in iis.

```
<system.webServer>
 <security>
  <requestFiltering>
   <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="206715200" />
  </requestFiltering>
 </security>
</system.webServer>
```

For a certain action, you can set a specific size according to different endpoints.

```
[HttpPost]
[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 20900)]
public IActionResult Upload(IFormFile file)
{
    //...
}
```